# Move a column using sed

Tags: bash, sed

My Awk script generates this output:

```
1396.0893854748604 jdbc:mysql 192.168.0.8:3306/ycsb 3
```

I need to put the final column at the start, but do not wish to swap its position with the first. I need to do this using sed, or another pipe that is not awk.

I have tried variants of this command, but with no luck. My output just stays the same.

```
sed 's@\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\)@\4,\1,\2,\3@g'
```

Just for clarity my desired output would look like this:

```
3 1396.0893854748604 jdbc:mysql 192.168.0.8:3306/ycsb
```

Comment: Why can't you do this in the awk command that's producing the output original? Given you're using awk for the first command, why couldn't you use it for the second one? This has the distinct odor of homework about it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use awk for this. It's better:

```
awk '{print $4, $1, $2, $3}' yourfilename
```

**Updated:** Oh right... Now I see that you require not using awk again... that's a wierd requirement. Leaving this here because it may be useful for future visitors.

Comment: Thanks, works great. The reason I wanted to use sed was because I did not want to pipe in another instance of awk, but I have managed to implement your answer into my original awk command.